# HTML Purifier and spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

Folders of my Page

```
system/ <-- offline files (classes, cronjobs, libraries ...)
online/ <-- contain all php scripts ( available online )

system/

classes <-- all my own classes inside.
... directories ...
libraries/htmlpurifier <- contain HTMLPurifier
```

I want to use spl_autoload_register()

```
<?php

define("DOC_ROOT", dirname(__DIR__));

function hTMLPurifier($class) {
 require DOC_ROOT . '/system/libraries/htmlpurifier/library/' . strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $class)) . '.php';
 }

 function myAutoload($class) {
 require DOC_ROOT . '/' . strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $class)) . '.php';
 }

spl_autoload_register('hTMLPurifier');
spl_autoload_register('myAutoload');


$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
?>
```

I get follow message.

```
 .../htmlpurifier_config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...
```

If insert

```
  "require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';"
```

on Top

```
<?php

define("DOC_ROOT", dirname(__DIR__));
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

function myAutoload($class) {
  require DOC_ROOT . '/' . strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $class)) . '.php';
 }


 spl_autoload_register('myAutoload');


 $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
 $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
 $clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
 ?>
```

Everything is work.

I want to load all classes with **spl_autoload_register()** only
without insert

```
"require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';"
```

on top.
How can, i do it???

Answer (score 0):

HTML Purifier doesn't work with PHP namespaces, so substituting `\\` with `/` won't net you the results you seek. Your autoload logic is trying to load the class `HTMLPurifier_Config` from the file `htmlpurifier_config.php` - so what you want is something like this:

```
function autoloadHtmlPurifier($class) {
    require DOC_ROOT . '/system/libraries/htmlpurifier/library/'
        . str_replace('_', '/', $class) . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('autoloadHtmlPurifier');
```

(Notice how this function doesn't use `strtolower()` and replaces `_` with `/`.)

But, looking at [the HTML Purifier autoload implementation](https://repo.or.cz/htmlpurifier.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/library/HTMLPurifier/Bootstrap.php#l58):

```
public static function getPath($class)
{
    if (strncmp('HTMLPurifier', $class, 12) !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // Custom implementations
    if (strncmp('HTMLPurifier_Language_', $class, 22) === 0) {
        $code = str_replace('_', '-', substr($class, 22));
        $file = 'HTMLPurifier/Language/classes/' . $code . '.php';
    } else {
        $file = str_replace('_', '/', $class) . '.php';
    }
    if (!file_exists(HTMLPURIFIER_PREFIX . '/' . $file)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $file;
 }
```

...there's a good chance the simple replacement will still not function correctly, because of the language class edge case. But you could try this:

```
function autoloadHtmlPurifier($class) {
    require DOC_ROOT . '/system/libraries/htmlpurifier/library/'
        . str_replace('_', '/', $class) . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('autoloadHtmlPurifier');
spl_autoload_register(array('HTMLPurifier_Bootstrap', 'autoload'));
```

That uses your custom autoloader to load the `HTMLPurifier_Bootstrap` class, so you don't need to include it with `require`, but still have the benefit of using the canonical autoloader for HTML Purifier.

### Word of caution

That said, in either case, the downside is that if HTML Purifier ever does switch to namespaces, your autoloader for it **will break**. I would really suggest you stick to the `require_once(DOC_ROOT . '/system/libraries/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php')` approach, or **install HTML Purifier using `composer`**, which will [take care of autoloading that library (and possibly others) for you](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading):

> For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a vendor/autoload.php file. You can simply include this file and start using the classes that those libraries provide without any extra work:
>
> ```
> require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
> ```